# How do I change the value of text field in wordpress contact form 7 using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change/input the value of in wordpress contact form 7 using javascript. I found that the form **id** can be identified in 3 ways

```
<label> [text your-name id:poo] </label>

<label id="poo"> [text your-name] </label>

<label> [text your-name html_id:poo] </label>
```

In all three ways, i tried the javascript method

```
document.getElementById("poo").value = "Jonny"
```

but the javascript code doesn't seem to have any effect on the form when displayed on the webpage. Any idea on how i can go about this?

I also did place the code in the form editor field, if that is a wrong section to write the code which may be the cause of it not being executed, please specify. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to figure out a way to resolve it and i guessed posting it here might help.

I checked the source code (ctrl + u) of the page where the contact form tag is located and I noticed that each tag is converted to an HTML language.
E.g

```
<label> <[text your_name id:poo ""] </label>
```

this will be converted in the page and display in the source code as

```
<input type="text" name="your_name" value="" id="poo" />
```

So the javascript code does not have to be placed on the contact form editor. Rather, it should be place on the page where the contact form short code is located: below is an example of the short code

```
[contact-form-7 id="289" title="Your contact form"]
```

So in the page where the short code is located, you can now use;

```
document.getElementById("poo").value = "jonny"
```

This will alter the value of the text field within the label tag.

Comment: To help future  visitors of this question you can mark your own answer as the correct answer (with a green checkmark) :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("poo").innerHTML = "Jonny"
```

Comment: I've tried that just and it didn't work. Besides, it's an input field and not a text paragraph, so it's not meant to use innerHTML property

Comment: You have to make sure the javascript is run after the html element is loaded. Did you try to place the javascript in the end of your page ?