# WP contact form 7: get current date value to populate an input field

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, date, contact-form-7

Using contact form 7 on my [website](http://wordpress.seefrau.at/buchen/), would like to retrieve the form submission date as an input value to use in "Jetpack CRM" for a custom field. I want to avoid that the user has to select the date with a date picker.

Until now i only managed to get the current date value with `[hidden today_date _date]` that i can use in email templates, but this is not the thing i need.

What i tried so far (after reading [How do I change the value of text field in wordpress contact form 7 using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50324094/how-do-i-change-the-value-of-text-field-in-wordpress-contact-form-7-using-javasc)):

In contact form 7, i added the field `<label> [text submission_date id:submissiondate ""] </label>`, hoping that the javascript would fill out the empty quotes with the dateTime value.

With the plugin "WP Headers and Footers" i added the script

```
    var today = new Date();

    var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();

    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();

    var dateTime = date+' '+time;

    document.getElementById("submissiondate").value = dateTime;
```

I tried the script in the header, in the body and in the footer.

The result is always: an empty form field and a js error:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Can anybody help me with this?

EDIT:
Searching for help in this question i got the advice to add `[hidden default:today_date _date id:submissiondate ]` to the form and enter the js in the footer, like this:

```
    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    var dateTime = date+' '+time;
    // this will set value for input with id submissiondate 
    jQuery('input#submissiondate').val(dateTime);   
    // check if value exists    
    var new_value = jQuery('#submissiondate').val();
    // display in console   
    console.log('current date time = ' + new_value);
```

Now the time value finds its way into the confirmation email, but still not into the jetpack crm custom field.
Maybe the problem is that this is a hidden field? I tried alternatively to add `[text default:today_date _date id:submissiondate ]` to the form to create another field in the hope that this can be used for a custom field in jetpack crm but this does not work either –  the custom field shows no value.
Does anybody know how to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION FOUND – a big shoutout to Santosh @ https://www.codeable.io/!
The line `[text default:today_date _date id:submissiondate ]` in the form was wrong – the correct line is `[text submissiondate id:submissiondate]`.

Summary: With the javascript in the page footer

```
    setInterval(add_date, 1000);    
    function add_date() {   
    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    var dateTime = date+' '+time;
    // this will set value for input with id submissiondate   
    jQuery('input#submissiondate').val(dateTime); 
    // check if value exists    
    var new_value = jQuery('#submissiondate').val();
    // display in console   
    console.log('current date time = ' + new_value);
    }
```

and the correct field `[text submissiondate id:submissiondate]` in the form template (hidden on the front end with CSS), i can use the field value in jetpack crm to populate a custom field and i can use it in a confirmation email as well. :-)

For those who prefer 2-digit-dates, the script can be edited like this:

```
    setInterval(add_date, 1000);    
    function add_date() {   
    var today = new Date();
    currentMonth = today.getMonth()+1;
    currentMonth = ("0" + currentMonth).slice(-2);
    currentDay = today.getDate();
    currentDay = ("0" + currentDay).slice(-2);
    currentHour = today.getHours();
    currentHour = ("0" + currentHour).slice(-2);
    currentMinute = today.getMinutes();
    currentMinute = ("0" + currentMinute).slice(-2);
    currentSecond = today.getSeconds();
    currentSecond = ("0" + currentSecond).slice(-2);
    var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(currentMonth)+'-'+(currentDay);
    var time = (currentHour) + ":" + (currentMinute) + ":" + (currentSecond);
    var dateTime = date+' '+time;

    // this will set value for input with id buchung-versanddatum   
    jQuery('input#buchung-versanddatum').val(dateTime);

    // check if value exists    
    var new_value = jQuery('#buchung-versanddatum').val();

    // display in console   
    console.log('current date time = ' + new_value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking out the stackoverflow page you mentioned, I noticed this:

> So the javascript code does not have to be placed on the contact form editor. Rather, it should be place on the page where the contact form short code is located: below is an example of the short code

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50333080/11017029

Maybe you didn't put your JavaScript code on the page where the contact form short code is located.

Comment: Thanks for checking! As far as i can see, the plugin "WP Headers and Footers" puts the JavaScript on all the website's pages. when i check the inspector on the page with the form the JavaScript is loaded – otherwise it would not show an error in the console, right?
i added a link to the form in my initial post to enable looking at it.